# can,t consuming php soapserver in C# winform

Tags: php, wsdl, soapserver

I have a simple php soapserver and I also created a wsdl file for it.I can consume it in php but I want to consume it in .net winform too.I searched about it but none of the suggested article was usefull. can you help me please?
here is my soapserver and the page name is testserver.php:

```
class TestClass
{
    function hello($someone) 
    {
        return "Hello " . $someone . " Welcome To Wsdl World!";
    }
    function SumData($a,$b) 
    {
        //return "this is test";
        return $a+$b;
    } 
}
   ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); 
   $server = new SoapServer("http://localhost/webservices/simple/test1.wsdl",array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
   $server->setClass('TestClass');
   $server->handle(); 
?>
```

and here is my wsdl file and the filename is test1.wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="MyDefinition"
                  targetNamespace="urn:myTargetNamespace"
                  xmlns:tns="urn:myTns"
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" >


    <wsdl:message name="sumincoming">
        <wsdl:part name="reqParam1" type="xsd:int"/>
        <wsdl:part name="reqParam2" type="xsd:int"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:message name="sumoutgoing">
        <wsdl:part name="resParam" type="xsd:string"/>
    </wsdl:message>


    <wsdl:message name="helloincoming">
        <wsdl:part name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:message name="hellooutgoing">
        <wsdl:part name="response" type="xsd:string"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:portType name="MyPortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="SumData">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:sumincoming"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:sumoutgoing"/>
        </wsdl:operation>

        <wsdl:operation name="hello">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:helloincoming"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:hellooutgoing"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>



    <wsdl:binding name="MyBinding" type="tns:MyPortType">
        <soap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="SumData">
            <soap12:operation soapAction=""/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal" namespace="urn:myInputNamespace" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap12:body use="literal" namespace="urn:myOutputNamespace" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

        <wsdl:operation name="hello">
            <soap12:operation soapAction=""/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal" namespace="urn:myInputNamespace" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap12:body use="literal" namespace="urn:myOutputNamespace" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="MyService">
        <!--<documentation>Returns a greeting string.</documentation>-->
        <wsdl:port name="MyPort" binding="tns:MyBinding">
            <soap12:address location="http://localhost/webservices/simple/testserver.php"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definition>
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio, if you right-click the project and select Add -> Service Reference... Place the wsdl address in the Address field and visual studio should create objects for calling your php soap server.

Your wsdl address based on the example would be

```
http://localhost/webservices/simple/test1.wsdl
```

Visual studio will show a list of Services:

```
MyPortType
MyService
```

Under my Port Type should be listed two operations

```
SumData
hello
```

Your wsdl file has a couple corrects required.

1. You need to define the wsdl namespace

   xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
2. The targetNamespace needs to match the same value as xmlns:tns

Below is the corrected wsdl file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="urn:myTns"
              xmlns:tns="urn:myTns"
              xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
              xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
              xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

<wsdl:message name="sumincoming">
    <wsdl:part name="reqParam1" type="xsd:int"/>
    <wsdl:part name="reqParam2" type="xsd:int"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="sumoutgoing">
    <wsdl:part name="resParam" type="xsd:string"/>
</wsdl:message>


<wsdl:message name="helloincoming">
    <wsdl:part name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="hellooutgoing">
    <wsdl:part name="response" type="xsd:string"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name="MyPortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="SumData">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:sumincoming"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:sumoutgoing"/>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="hello">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:helloincoming"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:hellooutgoing"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>



<wsdl:binding name="MyBinding" type="tns:MyPortType">
    <soap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="SumData">
        <soap12:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap12:body use="literal" namespace="urn:myInputNamespace" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap12:body use="literal" namespace="urn:myOutputNamespace" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="hello">
        <soap12:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap12:body use="literal" namespace="urn:myInputNamespace" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap12:body use="literal" namespace="urn:myOutputNamespace" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

</wsdl:binding>

<wsdl:service name="MyService">
    <!--<documentation>Returns a greeting string.</documentation>-->
    <wsdl:port name="MyPort" binding="tns:MyBinding">
        <soap12:address location="http://localhost/webservices/simple/testserver.php"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

The C# code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PHPSoapClient.MyPortTypeClient client = new PHPSoapClient.MyPortTypeClient();
        Console.WriteLine(client.SumData(1, 2));
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but I couldn,t call the function.could you  send or upload  a sample source please!?

Comment: I am having issues with the wsdl file you provided, trying to look into it.

Comment: Thanks a million and a billion my friend.It worked perfectly.